# "Invalid utf8mb4 character string" warnings on POINT fields when importing from a mysqldump

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I recently dumped a database as part of migrating it from an old server to a new server. Some of the tables have the `utf8mb4` character set as the default collation and as the character set for some of the fields.

One of the tables also has a field of type POINT. When I run `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 ... > dump.sql` and then try to import `dump.sql` I get the "Invalid utf8mb4 character string" warning for any rows that have a location set in the POINT field.

Do I need to worry about this? It looks to me like the data gets migrated correctly, but I do so dislike seeing warnings!

EDIT: Sample code and how to reproduce. The following is the output of `mysqldump` with no special options (adding the default utfmb4 charset option didn't help), on an example table of an example database. The table has one row:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;       
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;

CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `LatLong` point NOT NULL,      
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),     
  SPATIAL KEY `LatLong` (`LatLong`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `Items` VALUES (1,'item1','\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?4??=@\??O@?V?');
```

If you run from with mysql `source file.sql` on the file containing this SQL you get the following warnings on the insert:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'BE141E'
```

Further information:

```
> file -i file.sql
file.sql: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Strange.  Can you show us an example of what is in the dump file.

Comment: I have updated the post with a sample dump

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another symptom of https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80150 .
Fixed in MySQL 5.7.23, 8.0.12. Changelog: "If mysqldump or mysqlpump were used to dump binary data without the --hex-blob option, reloading the dump file could produce spurious warnings (values were inserted correctly regardless of the warnings). Such values are now written preceded by the _binary introducer to
silence the warnings."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :) 
Also your signature at the end will likely be edited out